# MS Access Pie Chart Legend combo

Tags: ms-access

I have created a pie chart from a query using the wizard in MS Access 2010. The chart is updated from a combo box and works perfectly fine, however the issue I am having is that because the query is referencing a combo box for the segments when the legend is displayed instead of using the second "text description" field it is showing the unique ID.

I was wondering if potentially there is a criteria that I could use to instead display the text column?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A query object cannot recognize Column property of combobox. So have a textbox on form reference the column and then the query will reference the textbox. So expression in textbox like:

`=ComboboxName.Column(x)`

x is the column index. Index begins with zero so if the data is in second column its index is 1.

Alternatively, construct SQL statement in Chart RowSource property which can reference the combobox Column property.